# New delta shower body install water running out of tub spout & shower head

Tags: water, shower, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, delta

Insalled 2 new delta shower bodys in same house complete renovation 1st bath no issues 2nd bath have water coming out tub & shower at the same time put 3 loops in pipe already returned shower body incase its defective plumbing is ½ cpvc pipe need help I checked all lines everything looks clear not sure what eles to do

Comment: Is the valve body upside-down, so what it thinks is the tub is actually the shower and vice versa? Not clear what you mean or were trying to accomplish with "put 3 loops in pipe" - please [edit] in a picture and explain your intent. Should be a short direct pipe to the spout and a longer direct pipe to the shower.

Comment: `tub & shower` it could be the diverter valve

Answer (score 1):

Could just be a bad glue job partially blocking the tub spout pipe. Did your checking allow you to see all the way to the elbow from both ends?